# I have got an error "Unable to mount volumes for pod ... " while trying to create pod with Helm, what I am doing wrong?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have k8s cluster with 1 master and 3 workers joined. When I am trying to install any application with helm I am always got same error like

```
"Unable to mount volumes for pod "jittery-woodpecker-openv-574f4f948f-
dqgxd_default(f79a5a72-ff71-11e7-8198-0ab01891413c)": timeout expired 
waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"jittery-
woodpecker-openv-574f4f948f-dqgxd". list of unattached/unmounted 
volumes=[certs]"
```

I am newbie in k8s and I was googling for some days, trying different k8s versions, reading docs but still can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you need to add more info on your manifest (specificaly volumes)

Comment: So  I should make some steps about volumes before `helm install ...` ? Can you please tell me about it or give some links, I can't find any info.